# How to insert a string date to a mysql database date field

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert a date String from my Java program to one of my MySQL database fields that has a date type.

```
package events;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
/**
*
* @author mewq
*/
public class ConDb {
public static void main(String[] args){
String description = null;
try{
Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tangkilikan", "user=root", "password=tangkilik");

Statement stat = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

String eventName = "Imba meeting";
String Address = "Zamora, Cabarroguis, Quirino";
Date date = '2011-09-09'; 
String description = "meeting";


String insert = "insert into events values ('" + eventName + "', '" + Address + "', ' + date + ', '" + description + "')";


stat.executeUpdate(insert);

} catch(Exception e) {

}

}

}
```

Comment: Post an example of what you're doing and the error you encounter.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

```
Date date = '2011-09-09';
```

won't compile. The correct approach to inserting date into a database table with a date type is to use a [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
String dateString = "2011-09-09";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse(dateString);

String insert = "insert into events values (?, ? , ? , ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatment(insert);
ps.setString(1, eventName);
ps.setString(2, Address);
ps.setDate(3, myDate);
ps.setString(4, description);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a  [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("05/15/11");
```

and use the resulting Date for the insert.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of convention, your variable/field/member names shouldn't start with a capital letter, so `Address` should actually be `address`.

As for your question, there's a problem with the creation of the `insert` String in the code you posted; you're not ending the string with a double quote (") before trying to concatenate your `date` field, so you're not going to end up with the String you're expecting. Try the following instead:

```
String insert = "insert into events values ('" + eventName + "', '" + Address + "', '" + date + "', '" + description + "')";
```

Comment: This won't work as it causes sql dependency injection,try to use prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

mysql date time format is '2013-01-01 01:00:00' OR YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS make sure you have that in quotes or ticks..

-> try casting that date object to a string.

best I can do without more info.